# Julia multidimensional array types?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I have an array of type `Array{Float64,2}` but it's an array of 1 column, and I'm unable to pass this into a function that's expecting a single-column array of type `Array{Float64,1}`. I don't really understand what the `2` means or how to fix my problem, and I haven't been able to figure it out by searching through any documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Array{Float64,2}`, the 2 is the number of dimensions in the array.  Since you say it's "it's an array of 1 column", you probably have something which is 2-dimensional with either one row or one column, i.e. one of

```
julia> c = rand(1,3)
1x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.190944  0.928697  0.251519

julia> d = rand(3,1)
3x1 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0818493
 0.0342291
 0.58341
```

To turn this into a 1-dimensional array, you could slice the array manually or use [`squeeze`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/arrays/#Base.squeeze), as you prefer:

```
julia> c[1,:]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.190944
 0.928697
 0.251519

julia> squeeze(d,2)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0818493
 0.0342291
 0.58341
```

Either approach should give you something of type `Array{Float64,1}`.

---

As noted in the comments, another approach is to use `reshape`, e.g. (using a different random `c`):

```
julia> reshape(c, length(c))
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.680653 
 0.0573147
 0.607054
```

This has the advantage -- and disadvantage -- of not caring whether you have an array of shape 1xN or Nx1.

Comment: randn is exactly what I was using. I don't understand why it returns a 2D array, though?

Comment: Are you maybe confused about the arguments that `randn` takes?  The arguments tell it what *shape* you want, not something like the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Ok, so `d = rand(3)` should get me `3-element Array{Float64,1}`? Why is a `3x1` array different from a `3-element` column vector?

Comment: No, it'll give you a 3-element `Array{Float64,1}`.  The 1 means you have a 1-dimensional object, so you can't have 3x1.  It's like the difference between a line 3 inches long and a rectangle 3 inches by 1 inch.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Another way of getting a 1D vector out of a 2D matrix (or N-D array) is to use the `reshape(A, dims...)` function.

Comment: `vec(c)`, where `c` is any Array also returns a vector. It is **very** quick, and will be correct in this case. But the result for higher-dimension matrices with several dimensions with more than one element depend on the implementation - use with understanding.