# How do I sum over a dimension in array while dropping the traversed dimension?

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to do a sum over one dimension in an array. That's easy. For an array 9x100x100:

```
sum(a,1)
```

However what is then left is an array with dimension 1x100x100. And now I want to get rid of the first dimension, since there is only one element left. So my solution is just:

```
reshape(summed_array, 100,100)
```

In order to get the 100x100 array, which I wanted.
However this does not feel very clean. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36524298/2541573

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Update

As [@E_net4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4) points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806584/how-do-i-sum-over-a-dimension-in-array-while-dropping-the-traversed-dimension/38806734#comment97523830_38806734) below, since Julia 1.0, you should use [`dropdims`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/base/arrays/#Base.dropdims) (a much better name!) rather than `squeeze`.

## Original answer

You're looking for [`squeeze`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/arrays/#Base.squeeze):

> `squeeze(A, dims)`
>
> Remove the dimensions specified by dims from array `A`. Elements of `dims` must be unique and within the range `1:ndims(A)`.

### Example

```
julia> a = rand(4,3,2)
4x3x2 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.333543  0.83446   0.659689
 0.927134  0.885299  0.909313
 0.183557  0.263095  0.741925
 0.744499  0.509219  0.570718

[:, :, 2] =
 0.967247  0.90947   0.715283
 0.659315  0.667984  0.168867
 0.120959  0.842117  0.217277
 0.516499  0.60886   0.616639

julia> b = sum(a, 1)
1x3x2 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 2.18873  2.49207  2.88165

[:, :, 2] =
 2.26402  3.02843  1.71807

julia> c = squeeze(b, 1)
3x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.18873  2.26402
 2.49207  3.02843
 2.88165  1.71807
```

Comment: There is no function `squeeze` since Julia 1.0. The same functionality is available in [`dropdims`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/base/arrays/#Base.dropdims).

Comment: @E_net4 Thanks; good to know. I'll update my answer accordingly.